# How can I get the Material Design Viewpager design and transition effect in android 4.0+ app

Tags: android, material-design

I'm using a ViewPager in my app but I would like to make it look exactly like the material design view pager. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the Android Developers blog post about how to achive Material Design features for Pre-Lollipop Devices: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/